# What is the most efficient way to determine if any two of three elements in an Excel VBA array are identical?

Tags: vba, excel

I am making a score sheet to keep track of the score in a quiz competition.  I have each of the three team's score being saved to an element of an array which I would like to check to determine whether there is a tie and which teams are tied.  Can anyone provide any guidance as to what the most efficient means of going about this is?

**Edit:**

I was hoping for something prettier than an if-statement (included as an answer below), but I don't have any better idea at this point.  Honestly, I'm not sure I understand why this got down voted.  It's true I haven't included the code I have because though I have thought about the problem for a while, I have not really known where to start.  In fact, I specifically asked to merely be provided some guidance with the proper means of going about this because I did not want to appear to be asking other people to do my work for me.  Nonetheless, I will show the logic I am trying to reproduce.  I'm not really sure what else I can do.

```
     Team Score      | Rank Description |   Team Tie ID
---------------------+------------------+-------------------
             / 250 \ | High Score       |            / 0 \
TeamScore1 = |  30 | | Low Score        | TeamTie1 = | 0 |
             \  60 / | Middle Score     |            \ 0 /
---------------------+------------------+-------------------
             / 250 \ | High score *TIE* |            / 1 \
TeamScore2 = |  30 | | Low Score        | TeamTie2 = | 0 |
             \ 250 / | High score *TIE* |            \ 1 /
---------------------+------------------+-------------------
             / 250 \ | High Score       |            / 0 \
TeamScore3 = |  30 | | Low Score *TIE*  | TeamTie3 = | 2 |
             \  30 / | Low Score *TIE*  |            \ 2 /
```

Basically, whenever any of the teams are tied at the end of a quiz, those two teams are asked more questions till their score changes to remove the tie.  I want to be able to detect when the teams are tied by producing the `TeamTie` array based on the `TeamScore` array.  If the best way to accomplish this is by using an if-statement, then fine, but I just though there might be an easier way.

Comment: Please show your existing relevant code.

Comment: Is the first column the Team Score Array?  Is the third collumn the TeamTie array?  What is the significance of the 2nd column?  How do you populate the first column?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, sorry, is that more clear?  The scores shown in the first column are calculated based on several factors regarding how well the quizzers did in answering questions correctly.  I can attempt to explain this, but it really seems like extraneous information that would just distract from the question I'm trying to get answered.

Comment: @tlewis3348 I don't understand your layout, but since you have an answer you can use, I won't pursue this further.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Uhh...  Okay.  I'm not sure I understand what there is to not understand.  I wish I could make things more clear, but I guess this question hasn't been as helpful as I thought it would be.  Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to Question:**

No matter what, there is no way to get the needed information without looping over the data.

You can use a combination of the `WorksheetFunction.Large` method and the `WorksheetFunction.Match` method to get the rank corresponding to each team.

To test whether a tie occurred, you will need to use the `SumProduct` function.  See the end of this article (http://goo.gl/o9po) for how to use this in VBA, as it can be somewhat tricky and non-intuitive.

**Note:** While I was not expecting, nor requiring anything more than the above information to mark the question as answered (which I believe I made abundantly clear in my question), more would have been no doubt helpful.  In light of that, for the benefit of people who may come in the future, here is the code I ended up using:

```
Sub Test4Tie()
    ' Variable declaration
    Dim TeamScore(1 To 3) As Integer, NumTeams As Integer
    Dim TeamRank(1 To 3) As Integer, ScoreCount(1 To 3) As Integer
    Dim iTT As Integer, TeamScoreSrt(1 To 3) As Integer
    Dim TeamTie As Boolean, TeamScoreStr As String

    'Input the score for each team
    TeamScore(1) = 250
    TeamScore(2) = 30
    TeamScore(3) = 30

    'Input the number of teams
    NumTeams = 3

    For iTT = 1 To NumTeams
        ' Sort the teams from highest to lowest score
        TeamScoreSrt(iTT) = WorksheetFunction.Large(TeamScore, iTT)

        ' Create list of team scores to count the number of occurances of each score in
        If iTT < NumTeams Then
            TeamScoreStr = TeamScoreStr & CStr(TeamScore(iTT)) & ","
        Else
            TeamScoreStr = TeamScoreStr & CStr(TeamScore(iTT))
        End If
    Next iTT

    For iTT = 1 To NumTeams
        ' Count the number of occurances of each score
        ScoreCount(iTT) = Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--({" & TeamScoreStr & "}=" & TeamScore(iTT) & "))")

        ' Get the rank of each score
        TeamRank(iTT) = WorksheetFunction.Match(TeamScore(iTT), TeamScoreSrt, 0)

        ' Detect ties
        If ScoreCount(iTT) > 1 Then
            TeamTie = True
        End If
        Debug.Print "TeamScore: " & TeamScore(iTT) & ", ScoreCount: " & ScoreCount(iTT) & ", TeamRank: " & TeamRank(iTT) & ", TeamTie: " & TeamTie
    Next iTT
End Sub
```

Here is the output when the code is run:

Input:

```
TeamScore = {250, 30, 60}
```

Output:

```
TeamScore: 250, ScoreCount: 1, TeamRank: 1, TeamTie: False
TeamScore: 30, ScoreCount: 1, TeamRank: 3, TeamTie: False
TeamScore: 60, ScoreCount: 1, TeamRank: 2, TeamTie: False
```

Input:

```
TeamScore = {250, 30, 250}
```

Output:

```
TeamScore: 250, ScoreCount: 1, TeamRank: 1, TeamTie: False
TeamScore: 30, ScoreCount: 1, TeamRank: 3, TeamTie: False
TeamScore: 50, ScoreCount: 1, TeamRank: 2, TeamTie: False
```

Input:

```
TeamScore = {250, 30, 30}
```

Output:

```
TeamScore: 250, ScoreCount: 1, TeamRank: 1, TeamTie: False
TeamScore: 30, ScoreCount: 2, TeamRank: 2, TeamTie: True
TeamScore: 30, ScoreCount: 2, TeamRank: 2, TeamTie: True
```

Answer (score 0):

For two out of three:

```
Public Function teext(SomeArray) As Boolean
    teext = False
    If SomeArray(1) = SomeArray(2) Or SomeArray(2) = SomeArray(3) Or SomeArray(1) = SomeArray(3) Then
        teext = True
    End If
End Function
```

for larger arrays I would use a **Collection**

Comment: That may work. I was hoping for something a little prettier, but I guess that's not a huge deal.